# Unable to store values values in Angular service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a Session service in AngularJS, but I'm having trouble storing values in it.
Am I storing or fetching the values wrong?
The pattern I'm trying to implement is described by Gert Hengeveld in his article [Techniques for authentication in AngularJS applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#c281)

**app/assets/javascripts/app/controllers/SessionCtrl.js.coffee**

```
app = angular.module "my_app"
app.controller 'SessionCtrl', ['$scope', 'Session', '$http', '$window', 
($scope, Session, $http, $window) ->


  getUserToken = (username, password) ->
    params = { grant_type: "password", username: username }

    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: "http://app.dev/oauth/token"
      params: params
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      console.log('getUserToken ' + data.access_token) // Outputted with the token I received.
      Session.create(data.access_token)
    ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->


  $scope.hi_there = 'martin'
```

**services/session.js**

```
app = angular.module('trenger')
app.service('Session', function () {
    this.create = function (accessToken) {
      console.log('in Sesssion create: ' + accessToken); // Seen in the console
      this.accessToken = accessToken;
    };
    this.destroy = function () {
      this.accessToken = null;
    };
    console.log('accessToken seen from the service: ' + this.accessToken ); // Not seen in console
    return this;
  });
```

**application.html**

```
      <strong> Session.accessToken {{ Session.accessToken }}  </strong> # Nothing
      <em>     Other val from SessionCtrl: {{ hi_there }}     </em>     # This works
```

Comment: itcouldevenbeaboats answer is certainly correct. However, I am wondering if you really didn't get a better error message in your javascript engine. using FF I get `userId is not a function`, in chrome `TypeError: string is not a function`. Both are pretty clear error messages

Answer (score 4):

`userId` is a property, not a function, therefore

```
  console.log(Session.userId)
```

Would work better.

Comment: Thanks, your're right!  Unfortunalty I'm still not able to read from the Session. Can you see any more stupid mistakes? :-)  Please see my updated code including markup.

Comment: Are you sure that Session.userId is the correct way? I'm trying to follow the session technic described here: https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232  BTW, neither Sessions.accessToken nor Session.accessToken() works.